# Copying docker containers to other computer without docker repo,docker save or commond

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-16.04, devops

I was having docker containers running in UBUNTU16.04 LTS machine but unfortunately, HDD crashed and I lost some of the data in bad sectors. but I backed up almost 90% data successfully.

I want to copy all the containers from backup to newly installed UBUNTU18.04 LTS

I tried to chroot in the home of the backup  but  I am not able to start Docker demon running in it

```
root@a-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:~# chroot /home/a/Documents/Mangesh/backup_root/
root@a-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:/# docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
root@a-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:/# service docker status
* Docker is not running
root@a-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:/# service docker start
* Starting Docker: docker                                                                                                               [ OK ] 
root@a-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:/# service docker status
* Docker is not running
```

is it possible to copy docker container file to newly installed docker directories to get a container running

Old OS - UBUNTU16.04 LTS
NEW OS -  UBUNTU18.04 LTS

Comment: May [this post](https://linuxconfig.org/docker-container-backup-and-recovery) can help you?

Comment: juanlumn thank you for the reply but my older ubuntu installation is damaged and as you can see in error I am unable to run docker demon so I cannot run docker save command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I found an answer there is a way to copy the docker container from one os to another without using Docker demon

Docker stores all the containers in the following directory

`/var/lib/docker`

> **On Machine from where you want to copy the containers**

so copy the /var/lib/docker folder with  root permission
if you are coping it through removable media

```
sudo cp -r /var/lib/docker /media/username/removable_media
```

> **On Machine to where you want to copy the containers**

Connect removable media to this machine
Stop the docker demon

```
sudo service docker stop
```

If there is already docker folder in **/var/lib/**  directory(it will be there in most cases) take a backup of docker folder in same folder

```
sudo mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker_backup
```

copy docker folder one which is there in removable media  to /var/lib/

```
sudo mv /media/username/removable_media/docker /var/lib/docker
```

now start/restart docker daemon

```
sudo service docker restart
```

As docker will have to update docker daemon will take a minute or two   to start  once  restarted you can check all containers are available again using

```
sudo docker ps -a
```